# Need some help computing the homology of a quotient of $T^2\times[0,1]$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have to admit that I spent a while now thinking about the question below. I could see that the map f takes integers to integers keeping thus taking the vertices of $T^{2}$ to vertices of $R/Z$. I am thinking about Mayer vietoris but how no idea how to map $T^{2}$x$0$ to $T^{2}$x$1$ "in order to compute the homology of the quotient space"

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: What is your question? What you quote is not a question, it's a definition (of $X$).

Comment: @Arturo. Thank you for your remark. I am supposed to compute the homology of the quotient space.

Comment: Could you please add that to the question  to clarify it? It's also not clear to me whether you are having trouble conceptualizing what $X$ is, or just with computing the homology of $X$.

Comment: @Arturo I want to compute the homology .I would be grateful to you if you also could help me understand how f works on homology

Comment: please edit your question to that it becomes a question. Not in the comments: in the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint for how to apply Meyer-Vietoris: Consider two open sets $U,V\subset [0,1]$, where $U$ contains the endpoints, and $V$ contains the middle.  $U\cap V$ will have two connected components.

Now, consider $U',V'\subset X$ given by $U'=T^2\times U$ and $V'=T^2\times V.$.  Because $f$ is an invertible linear map, both $U'$ and $V'$ are homotopy equivalent to $T^2$, $U'\cap V'$ is homotopy equivalent to two copies of $T^2$.

Note that care must be taken, as $f$ will affect what the inclusion maps in the MV sequence look like.  If you can determine how, the rest will fall out.